# Referencing nested dictionary keys in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I need help figuring out how to reference a key of a nested dictionary without specifically mentioning the name of the nested dictionary itself. Here's the dictionary:

```
rooms = {
    'Great Room': {'name': 'Great Room', 'Go North': 'Master Bedroom', 'Go South': 'Kitchen', 'Go East': 'Upstairs Hall', 'Go West': 'Outside'},
    'Master Bedroom': {'name': 'Master Bedroom', 'Go South': 'Great Room', 'Go East': 'Bathroom', 'item': 'Bear Mace'},
    'Bathroom': {'name': 'Bathroom', 'Go West': 'Master Bedroom', 'item': 'Painkillers'},
    'Kitchen': {'name': 'Kitchen', 'Go North': 'Great Room', 'Go East': 'Storage Room', 'item': 'Bandages'},
    'Storage Room': {'name': 'Storage Room', 'Go West': 'Kitchen', 'item': 'Fireworks'},
    'Upstairs Hall': {'name': 'Upstairs Hall', 'Go North': 'Spare Bedroom', 'Go West': 'Great Room', 'item': 'Flashlight'},
    'Spare Bedroom': {'name': 'Spare Bedroom', 'Go South': 'Upstairs Hall', 'item': 'Lighter'},
    'Outside': {'name': 'Outside', 'Go East': 'Great Room', 'item': 'Grizzly Bear'}
}
```

And the line referencing the nested key is:

```
if command == ('Pick up {}' .format(rooms['Master Bedroom'['item']])):
```

I need to be able to reference the 'items' key without explicitly naming the first key, 'Master Bedroom', 'Bathroom', etc. I also need to add input validation to ensure you can only pick up an item while in the same room as it, meaning you cannot pick up the Bandages while in the Bathroom and other examples like that. Not sure how to proceed.

I initially tried to do

```
if command == ('Pick up {}' .format(rooms['item']
```

But this obviously gives a key error

EDIT:

I guess I should've just pasted my entire script the first time, here it is:

```
# Define function to print game description and give player movement and item commands
def user_instructions():
    print('\nWelcome to "Alaskan Wilderness: A Grizzly Affair," the text-based game!')
    print('A late night ambush by a grizzly bear has left you injured and trapped your friends in the car!')
    print('You must search the cabin for six items to tend to your wounds and scare off the bear to save your friends!')
    print('Items to find: Bear Mace, FlashLight, Fireworks, Lighter, Bandages, Painkillers')
    print('If you try to face the bear before collecting every item, you will not survive the encounter!')
    print('Movement Commands: Go North, Go South, Go East, Go West')
    print('Item Pickup Commands: Pick up "item name"')
    print('To exit the game, type "Quit"')
    print('Warning: Movement, item pickup, and game exit commands are case sensitive!\n')


# Create dictionary of cabin rooms
rooms = {
    'Great Room': {'name': 'Great Room', 'Go North': 'Master Bedroom', 'Go South': 'Kitchen', 'Go East': 'Upstairs Hall', 'Go West': 'Outside'},
    'Master Bedroom': {'name': 'Master Bedroom', 'Go South': 'Great Room', 'Go East': 'Bathroom', 'item': 'Bear Mace'},
    'Bathroom': {'name': 'Bathroom', 'Go West': 'Master Bedroom', 'item': 'Painkillers'},
    'Kitchen': {'name': 'Kitchen', 'Go North': 'Great Room', 'Go East': 'Storage Room', 'item': 'Bandages'},
    'Storage Room': {'name': 'Storage Room', 'Go West': 'Kitchen', 'item': 'Fireworks'},
    'Upstairs Hall': {'name': 'Upstairs Hall', 'Go North': 'Spare Bedroom', 'Go West': 'Great Room', 'item': 'Flashlight'},
    'Spare Bedroom': {'name': 'Spare Bedroom', 'Go South': 'Upstairs Hall', 'item': 'Lighter'},
    'Outside': {'name': 'Outside', 'Go East': 'Great Room', 'item': 'Grizzly Bear'}
}


# Create list of cardinal directions to be used in the game loop for input validation
directions = ['Go North', 'Go South', 'Go East', 'Go West']

# Create empty list for player inventory
player_inventory = []

# Establish a dictionary housing the room the player is currently in, initially assigning it to the start room
current_room = rooms['Great Room']


# Define function to output user status, including current room, any items in current room (not including the starting room), and inventory
def user_status():
    print('You are in the {}' .format(current_room['name']))
    if current_room != rooms['Great Room']:
        if current_room['item'] not in player_inventory:
            print('You see the {}' .format(current_room['item']))
    print('Inventory:', player_inventory)


# Define function to pick up item, add it to player_inventory, and confirm pickup
def pickup_item():
    player_inventory.append(current_room['item'])
    print('You picked up the {}' .format(current_room['item']))


# Define functions for invalid room and item pickup commands
def invalid_move():
    print('You cannot go that way!')


def invalid_pickup():
    print('You cannot pick that item up here!')


# Establish empty string variable to be used later in the game loop
command = ''

# Print user_instructions()
user_instructions()

# Create game loop, first outputting user_status function
while True:
    user_status()

    # Create if branch to print victory/defeat statement if player is in the appropriate room, also depending on how many items they have retrieved
    if current_room == rooms['Outside']:
        if len(player_inventory) == 6:
            print('You managed to scare off the bear and save your friends, you win!')
            break
        else:
            print('You were devoured by the bear in front of your friends, you lose!')
            break

    # Reassign command variable to ask for and store user input
    command = input('Enter a move: ')

    # Create if-else branch to designate different output responses to the various possible player input, starting with an exit from the game
    if command == 'Quit':
        print('\nYou have quit the game, thanks for playing!')
        break

    # Create nested branches to control movement commands
    elif command in directions:
        if command in current_room:
            current_room = rooms[current_room[command]]
        else:
            invalid_move()

    # Create nested branches to control item pickup commands
    elif command == ('Pick up {}' .format(rooms[current_room]['item'])):
        if rooms['item'] in current_room:
            pickup_item()
        else:
            invalid_pickup()

    # Finish if-else branch by giving output for invalid input
    else:
        print('Invalid Input!')
```

The code I'm having trouble with is near the bottom, specifically lines:

```
    # Create nested branches to control item pickup commands
    elif command == ('Pick up {}' .format(rooms[current_room]['item'])):
        if rooms['item'] in current_room:
            pickup_item()
        else:
            invalid_pickup()
```

I need to be able to make sure that the player can ONLY pick up an item if they are in the same room as it.

Comment: How do you plan to reference the keys in the outer dict if it's not explicitly? I mean, how would your program know whether it must choose `['Master Bedroom']['item']` or `['Bathroom']['item']`?

Comment: What you're asking doesn't make sense, of course..  You can't pick an item unless you know which room.  Presumably, you have a variable that stores the current room.  So, you need `rooms[room]['item']`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask] for tips like how to write a good title. It's unclear how your program works, so please make a [mre]. But I think Tim's probably right on.

Comment: For input validation, I guess you want something like `elif command.startswith('Pick up'): print("That item doesn't exist here")`

Comment: Hint: what is the code that would give you `{'name': 'Master Bedroom', 'Go South': 'Great Room', 'Go East': 'Bathroom', 'item': 'Bear Mace'}`? If you had that, how would you get `'Bear Mace'` out of that? What happens if you try putting those things together? Hint 2: what is the difference between `function(x, function(y, z))` and `function(function(x, y), z)`?

Comment: `if command == ('Pick up {}' .format(rooms['Master Bedroom'['item']])):` You have the closing square bracket in the wrong place.  It should be `if command == ('Pick up {}' .format(rooms['Master Bedroom']['item'])): `

Comment: Sorry, it seems I've misunderstood. "I need to be able to reference the 'items' key without explicitly naming the first key, 'Master Bedroom', 'Bathroom', etc." - **how should it know which** inner dictionary to use? **What should happen**, if there is more than one room that has an item in it? "I also need to add input validation to ensure you can only pick up an item while in the same room as it" - **what does this mean**? **How do you know** what room the player is in - how is that represented in the code?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing magical about nested dictionaries.

If you have a dictionary named `mydict`, then you can access a key inside of that dictionary by putting `['key']` after the dict, like so:

```
mydict['somekey']
```

If that item is itself a dictionary, then you would access its keys **by doing the exact same thing** -- putting `['key']` after, like so:

```
mydict['somekey']['someotherkey']
```

And if *that* item is also itself a dictionary, then the exact same pattern continues:

```
mydict['somekey']['someotherkey']['yetanotherkey']
```

Do you see?  That's nothing special here.  It's all standard.

So what is your exact issue?